# Additional routes for pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In typo3-9 I have page URLs like:

- [www.mypage.com/page/](http://www.mypage.com/page/)
- [www.mypage.com/anotherpage/](http://www.mypage.com/anotherpage/)

Now I need these pages to be available also under links like:

- [www.mypage.com/test,page,1.html](http://www.mypage.com/test,page,1.html)
- [www.mypage.com/abcd,anotherpage,23.html](http://www.mypage.com/abcd,anotherpage,23.html)

Generally, [www.mypage.com/{1},page,{2}.html](http://www.mypage.com/%7B1%7D,page,%7B2%7D.html) should show page [www.mypage.com/page/](http://www.mypage.com/page/) and {1} could be any letters, and {2} any numbers. I need {1} and {2} to be visible in the page URL (without 301 redirect), for JavaScript purposes.

Is this possible to configure with some routeEnhancers?

Comment: This would be a multiple content issue. What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is a much better solution.

Comment: I've set link rel="canonical" on page head, so multiple content issue is no problem (for SEO). This is old service which I try to upgrade from Typo3-8 to Typo3-9. It has extensions which work with realurl - so I need to change it to the "new" typo3 routing.
My purpose - Typo3 shows the same page uder urls www.mypage.com/page/ and www.mypage.com/test,page,1.html.
There are lot of old links (in the internet) which look like this: www.mypage.com/test,page,1.html (from old versions of page) and I've to handle them

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be redirects, as you already provide the pages with a new canonical URL.

Similar to redirects would be rewrites, which are handled on server side without noticing the client (browser) (no 301).

---

BTW: be careful if you only work on the page name as it might not be unique. In the end only the page ID found in `{2}` identified the page.